# ajax popup center in body load from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i want to load popup in body center how to do it.. here is my all codes.. plzz help me for it.. thanks...

**head style**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.bpopup-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/scripting.min.js"></script>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
      jQuery(function ($) {

        $('.button').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).data('id');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/shopping/ajax.php',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (html) {
                    $('body').append(html);
                    $(html).bPopup();
                },
                error: function (returnValue) {}
            });
        });


    });
</script>
```

**Button html**

```
<button type="button" class="button small pop1" data-id="1521" >Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: Why are you appending html to body ?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean somthing like this after success you input in html and cheng css set

```
 success: function (html) {
     $('#popup').append(html);
     $('#popup').css('display','block');
     $(html).bPopup();
 },
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/uzwL48k2/

Answer (score 0):

css `margin : 0px auto` is missing to your div with id `#popup`

Apply this css

```
#popup {margin: 0px auto;}
```